# How to Reduce the Install Size of a Spacy based Python Application

Tags: python, spacy

I'm building a docker container that contains a the Python library [spacy](https://spacy.io/). I'm now trying to reduce the size of this container, and spacy appears to be the main contributor to the disk size.

Without any models installed, and without any other code/dependencies etc, spacy consumes around 500MB of disk when installed! Does anyone have any useful hints/tips on installing spacy in a disk-space-friendly manner.

My repro steps are:

```sh
mkdir foo1                  # create a folder 
cd foo1                     # change directory
python3 -m venv .venv       # create virtual environment
source .venv/bin/activate   # activate virtual environment
pip install --upgrade pip   # upgrade pip
pip install spacy           # install spacy
```

After doing this, I then navigate into the following folder...

`foo1/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

... and can see that the spacy folder is very large:

```sh
$ du -sh spacy
425M    spacy
```

Specifically, it's the language folder that's large:

```sh
$ du -sh spacy/lang
401M spacy/lang
```

There are 52 languages in that folder, and for many situations I only care about one or two languages. Specifically, for my current situation, that's English.

When I look at the sizes, English is the 14th largest (only showing the top 14 in this list)...

```sh
$ du -sH spacy/lang/* | sort -n -r 

142024 spacy/lang/tr
86608 spacy/lang/pt
78368 spacy/lang/nb
76592 spacy/lang/da
74840 spacy/lang/sv
60672 spacy/lang/ca
50880 spacy/lang/es
48296 spacy/lang/fr
41688 spacy/lang/de
36960 spacy/lang/nl
34008 spacy/lang/it
32632 spacy/lang/ro
24160 spacy/lang/lt
8712 spacy/lang/en  <--- THE ONLY ONE I WANT
```

Is there a spacy-specifc way of installing `spacy` without all of these languages?

I can hack around post-install, but is there a safer way to install fewer languages?

Versions installed, on MacOS, by the above steps are as follows:

```sh
$ pip freeze
blis==0.2.4
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
cymem==2.0.2
idna==2.8
murmurhash==1.0.2
numpy==1.16.4
plac==0.9.6
preshed==2.0.1
requests==2.22.0
spacy==2.1.6
srsly==0.0.7
thinc==7.0.8
tqdm==4.32.2
urllib3==1.25.3
wasabi==0.2.2

$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
```

Answer (score 2):

I raised this as an issue against the spacy project on GitHub, and it looks like this is a known issue, and that there are plans to address the size of spacy installs.

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3983

So, at this time, there isn't a supported/recommended way to reduce the size of the package install.

Answer (score 1):

If you tack an `&& rm -Rf foo1/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/lang/tr` onto the end of the `RUN pip install spacy` command that I presume you have in your `Dockerfile`, you can delete all the files for that language without letting them get saved into a layer in the Docker container.

I'm not sure if you would still have a working `spacy` after just ripping out the languages you didn't want, and you'd have to basically repeat the command for each language you *don't* want to keep, but it might work as a workaround until spacy makes itself smaller or more modular.

Comment: Yep. I'm going to try this, but as you say...not 100% sure I'd have a working install after that.